# how do you bit mask and shift the left most values in mips32?

Tags: mips, mips32

lets say I have a word in binary: 0111
I know that you can mask the right most value and shift right like this:

andi $10, $9, 1     # bit mask for $9, set mask to $10

bne $10, 1, outer_loop

srl $9, $9, 1

this with one iteration would turn the binary example to 0011 with $10 = 1

is there a way to do this but with the left most bit instead?
for example 0111 would turn to 1110 by shifting left but how do you get the mask equal to left most bit?

sorry for broken English, this is my second language.

Comment: _"is there a way to do this but with the right most bit instead? "_ That's what you're already doing. It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: Use constant 0x8 for `andi` .